# How to iterate through each row and collect data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Rows (id='row_property_'+number) in table contain four columns :

1. select element (id='multiple_object_type_'+number)
2. input type="text" (id='multiple_instance_id_'+number)
3. nested table (id='table_properties_'+number)
4. input type="button"

How to iterate through each row and collect data in two arrays from select and input with jquery ?

Comment: you can use jQuery with the function each (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)
and selct all Inputs / Selects by the id property? For example: 

$('input[name^="multiple_object_type"]') (http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: This should be an answer McPepper. :) you could get some rep for it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, add classes to the select and input elements so that the table looks something like this:

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td><select class="rowSelect"></select></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="rowInput" /></td>
    ... etc ...
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then you can get the values from each row like this in jquery:

```
$(function(){
  $('#myTable tr').each(function(){
    alert('select value is '+$(this).find('select.rowSelect'));
    alert('input value is '+$(this).find('input.rowInput'));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectArray = $('table tr td > select').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();

var inputArray = $('table tr td > input:text').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

This might do what you want.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MbMAx/)